# Ng-click does not trigger on appended items in directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have a simple directive that appends a button to my dom. However, the ng-click function on that button is not firing. What am I doing wrong?

```
app.directive("addwidget", function($compile) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var currentVal, wigetId;
        element.on("click", function() {
            if (this.checked) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('space-for-widgets'))
                    .append($compile("<button ng-click='removeWidFromPage()'>Hello World</button>")(scope));
            }
        });
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: link
    }
});

    app.directive('widget',  function(){
    return{
        restrict:'AE',
        template:'<div id="space-for-widgets"></div>' ,

    };  
});
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller("mainController", ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
    $scope.removeWidFromPage = function(){
        $window.alert("button called");
    } 
}]);
```

Here is a link to my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/qaKKN6LFnLV4uBRgOi2H?p=preview

Comment: You need to compile after appending.

Comment: Seems working here http://plnkr.co/edit/cbNxO8WoGX8KypJIgnHP?p=preview could you reproduce in plunkr

Comment: Your plunker has an error - there is no `appDirectivesdirective`; change to `app.directive`. But even so, this is a mess of a code. First, you can only have 1 unique id, so having a widget with with `id="space-for-widgets"` means that it is the only widget that could be there. Why then do you have a separate `addwidget` directive. Also, directives mainly deal with their own DOM subtree, so having a directive that does `document.getElementById` is weird. Also, think hard about your View Model and decide what is of concern to the controller and what is of concern to the `widget` directive.